# Get Vm's from RG with a particular tag value and update vm tags

Tags: powershell, azure

I'm trying to do is check a tag from a RG which has been set to true, and then for those resources (vms) in the RG (which are currently set to $False) set those to true. I've got an update script

Trying to write an IF statement, which will pull outall tags which are set to true and then loop through the vms and set a tag on them to $true, bit stuck on the loop,  if($OverRide -eq $true) {
       Get-AzureRmVM   .. thats about as far as I got :)

```
$x = Get-AzureRmVm -name "ThisVM" -ResourceGroupName "ThisRG"
$tags = $x.Tags
$tags['Shutdown'] = "$True"
$UpdateTag = Set-AzureRmResource -Tag $tags $x
```

But its how do i get the vms from the RG with override set to true and then loop through each vm setting it to false.

Trying to write an IF statement, which will pull outall tags which are set to true and then loop through the vms and set a tag on them to $true, bit stuck on the loop,

```
if($OverRide -eq $true) {
        Get-AzureRmVm -ResourceGroupname | Where-Object { $_.Tags['ShutdownSchedule'] -eq $false } |`
         ForEach-Object { $tags = $_.Tags; $tags['ShutdownSchedule'] = $true; `
         $_ | Set-AzureRmResource -Tag $tags }
```

Hope that makes more sense

Update..

something like that, gets all RG's similar to This-RG and gets the RG name and then passes that into a loop catching all vm's

```
$resourcegroup = get-AzureRmResourceGroup | where -FilterScript {
   $_.ResourceGroupName -like "This-RG*"
   }

$rgname = $resourcegroup | select resourcegroupname

Get-AzureRmVm | foreach ($rgname in $rgnames) 
{ 
Where-Object { $_.Tags['Shutdown'] -eq $false } | ForEach-Object`
{ $tags = $_.Tags; $tags['Shutdown'] = $true; $_ | Set-AzureRmResource -Tag $tags }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$resourceGroups = Get-AzureRmResourceGroups | Where-Object { $_.Tags['Shutdown'] -eq $false -and $_.Name -like 'This-RG*' }

$resourceGroups.ForEach({
    $vms = Get-AzureRmVm -resourceGroup $_.Name
    $vms.ForEach({
        $tags = $_.Tags
        $tags['Shutdown'] = $true;
        Set-AzureRmResource -ResourceId $_.Id -Tag $tags
    })
})
```

This will find all the resource groups with tag `shutdown` equals to false and change `shutdown` tag on all the vms inside those groups to true

Comment: Thanks, Tags are a pain. I'm getting this error  `Cannot index into a null array.
At line:1 char:61
+ ... ResourceGroup | Where-Object { $_.Tags['ShutdownSchedule_AllowStop']`
+                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray`

Comment: probably no tags
 on that resource group at all

Comment: Lol oh dear, that’s what happens when you have two teams doing two parts of the same job .. thanks so much ;)