# How delete VM Azure using tags using powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell, tags, virtual-machine

How do I delete a VM using tags? Let's say there is a VM with the tags "Name:Surname". How can I delete this VM without using the VM name or ID. Namely deletion using tags.
I try to use:

```
get-azvm -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroup" | Where-Object {$_.Tags -like "[Name, blabla], [Surname, blabla]"}
```

but it didn't find that VM

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get Vm's from RG with a particular tag value and update vm tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48340922/get-vms-from-rg-with-a-particular-tag-value-and-update-vm-tags)

Comment: See [Get Vm's from RG with a particular tag value and update vm tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48340922/get-vms-from-rg-with-a-particular-tag-value-and-update-vm-tags) for searching by tags, then pipe to Remove-AZVM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I have reproduced in my environment. Firstly, you need to find the Virtual Machine using the below command:***

***xx- Name of the resource group***

***hello- tag name***

```
get-azvm -ResourceGroupName "xx" | Where-Object {$_.Tags['hello']}
```

[image]

***After getting the VM name you can use the below command to delete the VM:***

***xx- Name of the resource group
yy- Name of the vm.***

```
Remove-AzVM -ResourceGroupName "xx" -Name "yy"
```

***Then type Y(yes) to delete the VM as below:***

[image]

***References taken from:***

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/remove-azvm?view=azps-8.2.0#example-1-remove-a-virtual-machine
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/get-azvm?view=azps-8.2.0

Comment: But tags consist of "key : value". How can I find VM using it? I have tag on VM "requestor : blabla@email.com"

Comment: Here key is "hello" and value i kept as "hi".

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48340922/get-vms-from-rg-with-a-particular-tag-value-and-update-vm-tags),
You could do something like this:

```
$Surname= 'Test'
$VMs = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName 'myRG'
foreach ($VM in $VMs)
{
    [Hashtable]$VMTag = (Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $VM.ResourceGroupName -Name  $VM.Name).Tags
    foreach ($h in $VMTag.GetEnumerator()) {
    if (($h.Name -eq "Name") -and ($h.value -eq $Surname))
        {
            Write-host "Removing VM" $VM.Name
            Remove-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $VM.ResourceGroupName -Name $VM.Name -Force -Confirm:$false
        }
    }
}
```